# Is this a thing? Visualizing complex functions with 3D animation

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, visualization

I have read about [various ways](http://www.pacifict.com/ComplexFunctions.html) to visual complex functions, e.g. colored graphs, vector fields, conformal maps, etc.

Here is another way: 3D animation. Picture a 3D plot with three axes for $\text{Re}(z), \text{Im}(z), \text{Re}(f(z))$. Press "play" and the plot starts moving, with time $t=\text{Im}(f(z))$. Alternatively, the three axes could be $|z|, \operatorname{arg}(z), |f(z)|$, with time $t=\operatorname{arg}(f(z))$.

Questions: Is this method of visualizing complex functions known? Could it be useful?

(Needham's book [*Visual Complex Analysis*](http://usf.usfca.edu/vca//) does not seem to mention this method.)

Comment: Suppose $f=\operatorname{Re}$. Then your $t$ is always $0$. I imagine you meant something like $t=\operatorname{Im}(z)$. In that case, using animations of slices for 4d things is a standard approach. I don't know how often it's used for complex functions, but I imagine using $t$ for a component like that isn't very useful for showing what's qualitatively important about most functions.

Comment: @MarkS. If $f=\operatorname{Re}$ then the 3D animation would be an instantaneous flash at $t=0$ of the plane $-x+y+z=0$. I'm not sure why $t=\operatorname{Im}(z)$ would be more useful than $t=\operatorname{Im}(f(z))$.

Comment: "I'm not sure why $t=\operatorname{Im}(z)$ would be more useful" At least two reasons: 1. Things like an instantaneous flash are hard to see without cheating the length of the flash, and that would make the visualization more complicated to set up and less precise. 2. To plot your way accurately on a single frame requires knowing in advance all of the inputs that give a particular output $f(z_0)$. But with something related to *the input* as the time parameter, then each frame only requires approximating things like $f(a+ti)$ for various values of a.

Comment: @MarkS. Thanks, here are my thoughts. When we plot individual points, we draw them larger than their actual size, to make them visible. Similarly, a flash in an animation could last longer than its true time length. As far as the technical challenges of creating an animation, I would hope that computers could handle them.

Comment: I have used this technique in my head and in classes, and am surprised to hear it seems to be not widely known. I propose to use different axes as "time" and compare the results, to get a better feeling. Also, it obviously works best for meromorphic functions, excluding $Re$ etc., and these are the most interesting ones anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen before a visualization like this, but I think it could be very interesting. Just like any other visualization technique:

- You need several interesting examples to "get used" to it. You need to learn how  features of a known visualization, or of the theory itself, fit int this new technique. What happens at poles or at zeros of meromorphic functions?, what happen in zeros with higher degree.
- Surely it won't be complete, in the sense that there will be features that cannot be seen. But hopefully some results of the theory could be better understood in this way.

I am really curious about what animations would arise with $z^2$, $\overline{z}$, $\frac{1}{z}$,... Please, if you finally develop this kind of representation, please paste links to the videos at the end of your question.